# What might be the reason for the error message indicating a superclass access check failure in a Java program in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Cause: superclass access check failed: class butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor$RScanner (in unnamed module @0x6f19d21b) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.tree to unnamed module @0x6f19d21b

I am trying to use the add to cart option in my app